# Merge two partitions without reinstalling Ubuntu in a dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have installed both Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 in my PC. My C drive on Windows is running out space, and I want to merge two partition as I need about 15GB to install Visual Studio in Windows. When I merge the two partitions inside Windows, the partition table will be changed and I will be unable access Ubuntu.

I did this few months ago, and I had to reset the Master Boot Record (through Windows recovery CD) to boot the PC, but when I reset the MBR I lost access to Ubuntu as the dual boot screen was lost and I had to reinstall Ubuntu again.

Is there a way to merge the two partitions in Windows without facing such a problem?

Partition Table

```
 Device    Boot    Start     End     Sectors   Size  Id  Type  
/dev/sda1              63 122881184 122881122  58.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda2       122881246 976766975 853885730 407.2G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)    
/dev/sda5       122881248 205214309  82333062  39.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda6       205214373 341716456 136502084  65.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda7       380692368 468214424  87522057  41.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda8       468230144 530101540  61871397  29.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda9       530102272 570628095  40525824  19.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda10      570630144 673028095 102397952  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda11      673034241 775425419 102391179  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda12      775436288 877823729 102387442  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda13      877838336 976766975  98928640  47.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT    
/dev/sda14      341716992 372492287  30775296  14.7G 83 Linux    
/dev/sda15      372494336 380690431   8196096   3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Please add the partition table results of the command `sudo fdisk -l` to your question which will show where the MBR is located.

Comment: @karel I have added the partition table. I have installed all my programs in D:\ drive, so i cant merge C: and D:  In my opinion , to merge two partition they has to be adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 0):

So one option that you could do if you have extra space on the Ubuntu partition. You can shrink the Ubuntu partition, and then with the unused space then expand the Windows partition.

Here is a link that talks about [resizing a partition in Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/).

Once you have the new unused space you can then expand the windows partition. Here is a link to [resize a partition in Windows.](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)

And here is another option on how to [resize the volume with easeus.](https://www.partition-tool.com/resource/windows-10-partition-manager/resize-partition-windows-10.htm)

Comment: My Ubuntu does not have that much space therefore it is not an option. Last time a tried both and ended up losing Ubuntu access . PLs see the partition table.

Comment: @Manoj so then I guess where are you trying to get the space from? If you do not have space on your windows partitions, or on the linux partitions then you are going to have to remove some data to make room for the program? The partition table does not show what space is available on the drives. regardless I believe easeus has the ability to merge partitions. I am not sure if it will do anything to the grub bootloader.